# Creating the same bin file as content of string C#

Tags: c#, bin

I would like to create a bin file for example file.bin with the same content as a string variable contains. For example I have string str="10101" and I want to create conversion of str's content to bin file. After conversion, when I open file.bin I want to see the same content as str: 10101. I tried to do that by this way:

```
string path = "files/file.bin";

string str = "10101"; 

File.Create(path);
BinaryWriter bwStream = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create));
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    binWriter.Write(str[i]);
}
binWriter.Close();
```

but i get exception like

> "System.IO.IOException: The process can not access the file
>   "`C:\path..`"

because it is being used by another process.. and few more exception.

Comment: Do you want to write the *string* 10101 or do you want to write actual binary representation (i.e bits)?

Comment: The error is because you open the file twice.  Just remove the `bwStream` line.

Comment: @Lloyd I want to write the string 10101

Comment: So you basically want a UTF-16 encoded text file with a content of `"10101"` and the file extension `bin` instead of `txt`? -- and the content (for another example) could could be exchanged for `"hello world!"` or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you are opening the file twice. The second time fails because the file is already open.

To write the string to the file you can just use the [`File.WriteAllText` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string path = "files/file.bin";
string str = "10101"; 
File.WriteAllText(path, str);
```

Note: The string is encoded as utf-8 when it is written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

The path/file you are trying to access is used by some other application. Close all the application which can/has opened the file,`file.bin`, which you are creating and then the code. It should work. You can remove `bwStream` variable line, if no other application is running.

Comment: And also make sure the file is in a location that you have permissions to write to...

Comment: Actually it's used by the same application as the OP opens a stream to the file and then a writer.

Comment: Yup, saw it and modified the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`File.Create()` uses the file, try:

```
File.Create(path).Dispose();
BinaryWriter bwStream = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite));
```